# Select DataTempate in a GridView according to group

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, datatemplate

I've got a few collections of items. All items has the same type:

```
public class ItemType 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Some of items are "favorites". They are the same, but I store them in a separate collection.
I have a goup of items class:

```
public class ItemsGroup 
{
   public List<ItemType> Items {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

So, some items are in one group, and some items are in "favorites" group. (Title = "Favorives".

Also, I have a page with a `<GridView>`. I want to set different data tempates according to group. (BigItem and SmallItem for example). I can achieve that by adding an extra field to `ItemType`:

```
public enum GroupType { Fav, Other; }

public class ItemType
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public GroupType Type {get; set;}
}
```

and select data template in `DataTemplateSelector` class

```
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var x = item as ItemType;
        if(x != null)
        {
            if(x.Type == GroupType.Fav) return FavDataTemplate;
        }
        return DefaultDataTemplate;

    }
```

But I don't want to add extra fields to ItemType, because it's a shared class (wp7, winrt ect).

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418511/how-can-i-make-groups-in-a-metro-gridview-use-different-layouts) , but I have the same problems.

Is there any way to select data template by group?

Comment: Having a favorites class that inherits from ItemType is not an option?

Comment: I deserialize ItemType from JSON, so I've just put in into the wrapper class, wich holds a Group and an ItemType.